# Increment directory name if it already exists

Tags: python, directory

If I have a directory that already exists, called Test. How can I increment the directory name by 1, if I try creating a directory with the same name?

Comment: This will be easier if you use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), part of the standard library instead of `os`.  [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

Comment: what about your code doesn't work?

Comment: I get a Traceback error, because the directory already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use either the **Recursive** or the **Loop** code.

**Notes:**

- Recursive code may result in an error (**maximum recursion depth exceeded**)
- Loop code, works well with no errors

**Code | Recursive**

```
import os

def generated_directory_name(name, x=0):
    dir_name = (name + (' ' + str(x) if x is not 0 else '')).strip()
    if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
        os.mkdir(dir_name)
        return dir_name
    else:
        return generate_directory_name(name, x + 1)

def create_directory():
    user_input = input("Enter name to create directory: ")
    generate_directory_name(user_input)

def main():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    create_directory()

main()
```

**Code | Loop**

```
import os

def generate_directory_name(name, x=0):
    while True:
        dir_name = (name + (' ' + str(x) if x is not 0 else '')).strip()
        if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
            os.mkdir(dir_name)
            return dir_name
        else:
            x = x + 1

def create_directory():
    user_input = input("Enter name to create directory: ")
    generate_directory_name(user_input)

def main():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    create_directory()

main()
```

**Output**

[image: Code Output]

Comment: I think this might add an extra space to the end of the user entered name. EDIT: My bad, didn't see the else.

Comment: it wont add extra spaces

Comment: you can change 1 of the lines to this `dir_name = (name + (' ' + str(x) if x is not 0 else '')).strip()` using the strip string function

Comment: @thecomputerguru no prob, glad to help. if you need anymore help in the future, just tag me and i'll have a look... cheers

Comment: Will do! Thank you!